# Get single record from each grouped set of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table that stores language information which I'd like to pull the most relevant data from. If the language you request is available, it should get that language. If not, then it should return a default.

The data looks like this:

```
ID  PARENT_ID   NAME    LANG
1   1           test    default
2   1           test    en-GB
3   1           test    fr
4   4           Hello   default
5   4           Hello   en-GB
6   4           Hola    es
```

If I want to get all the results for Spanish, then I should be able to get record 6 and record 1 because the first set doesn't contain a Spanish version. How would I go about this?

This is the nearest I can get with a query, but I *always* get the default and never the Spanish result:

```
SELECT h_id,
    h_faq_id,
    h_question,
    h_language
FROM
    h_itsm_faqs
WHERE
    h_language = 'default'
OR
    h_language LIKE 'es'
GROUP BY
    h_faq_id
ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN h_language LIKE 'es' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) ASC
```

I see the options as follows:

1. One query to get both (no idea how to do this)
2. Two queries to get both the language and the defaults and then work out which I need
3. Get all the results and sort through them

Option 1 would be fantastic, but it's worth noting that option 3 could be problematic when it comes to pagination.

Comment: Why are you comparing strings first with `=` and later with `LIKE` ?

Comment: Also, your GROUP BY will collapse the data before the ORDER BY can take place, so you will always get default

Comment: @Oli wether it's `=` or `LIKE` doesn't matter to me, but we've ensured the default is always lowercase and was just catering for cases where language may sometimes be capitalised as the data could come from multiple sources. I suspected something was happening with the `GROUP BY` but was hoping the `CASE` and the `ORDER BY` would happen first

Comment: Whats is a set based on?Name column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to join the table with itself using a left join. Then you can have the default and the specific language when it is available.

```
SELECT 
    f1.id,
    f1.parent_id,
    f1.name AS 'default_name',
    f2.name AS 'translated_name'
FROM
    h_itsm_faqs f1 LEFT JOIN h_itsm_faqs f2 ON (f1.parent_id = f2.parent_id AND f2.language LIKE 'es')
WHERE
    f1.language = 'default'
```